# Failure: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: File testfile_1.txt Line 1

Tags: java

Its me again...with the same context. I ran a test file in Dr.Java for my constructor. It is about reading a file in the directory to test. Here is part of content in test file:

```
public void cw_println_file1 () throws Exception {
String actual, msg, expect;
String filename;
CensoredWriter out;
for(int i=0; i<fileLines.length; i++){
  String [][] test = fileLines[i];
  String censor = test[0][0];
  String [] outLines = test[1];
  String [] expectLines = test[2];
  filename = String.format("testfile_%d.txt",i);
  out = new CensoredWriter(filename,censor);
  for(int j=0; j<outLines.length; j++) { 
  out.println(outLines[j]);
  }
  out.close();
  assertLines(expectLines, filename);
}
}
```

I got an error message like this:

File: C:\Users\jiangbuyun\Desktop\lab5\distrib-lab05\Lab05Tests.java  [line: 137]

**Failure:** org.junit.ComparisonFailure: File testfile_1.txt Line 1

**Expect:** A %!^*#@er-scooper, or %!^*#@ scoop, is a device used to pick up animal

**Actual:** A %!^*#@er-scooper, or %!^*#@ scoop, is a device used to pick up animalfeces from public places and yards, particularly those ofdogs. %!^*#@er-scooper devices often have a bag or bag attachment.

**Expected:**<...ed to pick up animal[]>

**but was:**<...ed to pick up animal[feces from public places and yards, particularly those ofdogs. %!^*#@er-scooper devices often have a bag or bag attachment.]

I found it is supposed to stop at the brackets after "animal" and nothing is between the two brackets, but it actually continued to read text and put it into the brackets.

```
public class CensoredWriter extends PrintWriter {

String censored;

public CensoredWriter(OutputStream o, String c) {
    super(o);
    this.censored = c;
}

public CensoredWriter(File f, String c) throws Exception {
    super(f);
    this.censored = c;
}

public CensoredWriter(String s, String c) throws Exception {
    super(s);
    this.censored = c;
}

public String transform(String s) {
    String a = s.replaceAll(censored, "%!^*#@");
    return a;
}

@Override
public void print(String s) {
    super.print(transform(s));
}

@Override
public void println(String s) {
    print(s);
    flush();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted, the issue is that you seem to replace `censored` with `"%!^*#@"`, so that part of the implementation works. However, stopping after `animal` is the part you haven't implemented yet.

By the way, when asking questions, try to provide the necessary context. For example, I suppose your method `cw_println_file1` is a test (`@Test`) method -- it would help to see that without guessing. Also, if your method requires some stuff from a `@Before` method (eg. `fileLines` seems to be declared somewhere else), it might help for the reader to understand your problem to see those required parts as well.